# append a space with jquery to inline anchor tags if there are more than one

Tags: jquery, css, centering

I have a wordpress foreach loop that will list categories as anchors for posts I create. They are listed inline and I would like to add a space between them if there are more than one listed. I tried to add a right margin on them but it messes up the centering.

```
<div class="catBoxBig">
 <?php   $exclude = array("Archive");
    $categories = get_the_category();   
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    if (!in_array($category->cat_name, $exclude)) {
        echo '<div class="catBox"><a class="catName" href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ).'">'.esc_html( $category->cat_name ).'</a></div>';
    }
} ?>
</div>
```

my css for centering:

```
.catBigBox {text-align:center;}
.catBox {display:inline;}
```

Comment: make them inline-block then they will naturally have a space between them or you could add equal margin to right and left

Comment: I tried inline-block but it didn't create a space between them

Comment: Are you sure: https://jsfiddle.net/emdqd5fn/2/ it should have the space the size of the font

Comment: I see it works in that fiddle but for some reason it doesn't work when I input my own code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add margin as follow:

```
    .catBox{
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 5px;
    }
```

this will add margin of 5px to left and right of each element with class .catBox

Answer (score 0):

I would either add a space at the end of the output string :

`echo '<div class="catBox"><a class="catName" href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ).'">'.esc_html( $category->cat_name ).'</a></div> ';`

The very last space at the end of the string is necessary if you display an element `inline` (or even `inline-block`) to prevent accidental concatenation.

Or the CSS way - add a margin right on each `div` but the last:

`.catBox:not(:last-child) {margin-right: 4px;}`